# How to use a crossword inside an xsim exercise?

Tags: exercises, xsim, puzzle

I was mandated to create some grid-based puzzles for the students. I planned to use the xsim package to separate the exercises, and cwpuzzle to create the puzzles. But the display was garbaged *inside* the exercise, as the example shows. *Outside* the exercise environment it was OK. I don't exactly know, what is colliding yet, so I need some help.

The example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cwpuzzle}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}[points=10]
\begin{Puzzle}{5}{3}
        |*   |*   |[1]E|X  |*   |.
        |[2]A|[3]S|T   |*  |[4]T|.
        |*   |[5]P|A   |R  |T   |.
\end{Puzzle}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image: And the output is:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puzzles from `cwpuzzle` are read verbatim. To preserve the handling of this content, `xsim` offers the `use-files` package option that stores the content of the question in a separate file. This in turn allows the verbatim content to be processed normally.

MWE (don't forget to delete all auxiliary files first if you tried to compile the document before applying the package option):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cwpuzzle}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[use-files]{xsim}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}[points=10]
\begin{Puzzle}{5}{3}
        |*   |*   |[1]E|X  |*   |.
        |[2]A|[3]S|T   |*  |[4]T|.
        |*   |[5]P|A   |R  |T   |.
\end{Puzzle}
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]